# React - Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation

Tags: reactjs, babel-loader

I want to use react-validation component `Input` in my form. This is why I imported it & used inside the form as:

```
<Input className="form-control"
       type="text"
       placeholder="name"
       value={props.data.creatingUser.createName}
       name="createName"
       id="createName"
       onChange={props.handleAddChange}
required/>
```

When I try to run the application using `npm start`, I receive the following error in the console:

> SyntaxError:
> E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-validation\src\components\input\index.js:
> Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't cur rently enabled
> (6:3):
>
> const Input = ({ error, isChanged, isUsed, ...props }) =>
> (
>
> > 
>
> ```
> |   ^        <input {...props} {...( isChanged && isUsed && error ? {        className: `is-invalid-input ${props.className}`
>  } : { className: props.className } )} />
> ```

**I have not explicitly done any babel configuration** and my `package.json` file has the following content:

```
{
  "name": "rental-application",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "popper.js": "1.16.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react-notifications": "^1.7.2",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.7.1",
    "react-table": "^6.11.4",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.12.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-table-6": "^6.11.0"
  }
}
```

My project structure:

```
++node_modules

++public
+++index.html
+++manifest.json
+++robots.txt

++src
+++App.js
+++index.js
+++index.css

++package.json
++package-lock.json
```

You can see I am not using any other configuration, and I have initiated the project using create-react-app command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input in react-validation lies under build folder. But from the error it seems that you didn't imported Input properly:
SyntaxError: E:\Projects\personal\rental-application\node_modules\react-validation\**src\components\input**\index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (6:3):

Can you please check your import statement? It should be something like this:

```
import Input from "react-validation/build/input";
```

Comment: Correct solution!

Answer (score 4):

#### 1st proposal

As it is suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335821/how-do-i-add-babel-preset-react-to-the-presets-section-of-babel-config-js) thread, run
`bundle exec rails webpacker:install:react`. It will add that bit to the babel.config.js automatically. You will not need to manually do something.

. . . . . .

#### 2nd proposal

You should install `@babel/preset-react` as it is suggested in the error message.

Using npm:

`npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react`

or using yarn:

`yarn add @babel/preset-react --dev`

See our website [@babel/preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react.html) for more information.
Ref:
https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-react

. . . . . .

#### 3rd proposal

Alternatively, if the first proposal doesn't work, as it is suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65248974/babel-config-error-support-for-the-experimental-syntax-jsx-isnt-currently-en), you should update `babel.config.js`, so it will work. So update the file as it is suggested:

```
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
    ['@babel/preset-react', {targets: {node: 'current'}}] // add this
  ]
};
```